# How to declare linearlayout in FrameLayout

Tags: java, android, android-framelayout

Now I am going on with my extends `FrameLayout`.

How can I declare a `LinearLayout` in that class.

For eg: `LinearLayout followButton =(LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.transperent);`

in normal Activity class how can i do this in below class

```
   Public class MyActivity extends FrameLayout {


    }
```

**> main.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/transperent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <TextView

      android:id="@+id/text1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />



    <TextView
      android:id="@+id/text2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

If anyone have idea about this please help me friends.

Comment: For what purpose you need to do that?

Comment: I want to give the whole linearlayout a id reference like this  android:id="@+id/transperent" to change the opacity level.

Comment: to do some changes to my layout.

Answer (score 0):

in the constructor of your custom FrameLayout you can use

```
inflate(context, R.layout.main, this)
```

this way, the `LinearLayout` will be added automatically to the `FrameLayout`

Comment: I want to give the whole linearlayout a id reference like this android:id="@+id/transperent" to change the opacity level.

Comment: then do it. Once you call inflate, the LinearLayout becomes part of   FrameLayout. You can use an instance of it to retrieve your LinearLayout using findViewById

Comment: Actually i new to android can gudie me by some examples